# Newbie setting up a ListView

Tags: android

I am just starting out using Android, so this is probably a very basic question.

I have created an array called priorityNames. I want to display that in a list and be able to make a selection from that list. At this stage, I cannot get the list to display.

As a starting point I used a short example from windrealm.org tutorials
Any help would be appreciated. Also if anyone can point me to a better example it would be appreciated.

```
public class SimpleListViewActivity extends Activity {    

private ListView mainListView ;    
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;    

/** Called when the activity is first created. */    
@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    

    // Find the ListView resource.     
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );   
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, R.array.priorityNames);    
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);          
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are passing just an id with R.array.priorityNames.

Use:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.priorityNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a TextView in your xml layout (simplerow.xml) with id:

```
...android:id="@android:id/text1"...
```